Unable to view an indented tree and a document embedding for this d3 project
I am learning visualization using D3 and was trying to execute this code on my browser for creating an indented tree to view taxonomy and to create a document embedding but unfortunately I can't view any of the charts on the browser.
The following is my indented-tree.js file:
import * as d3 from "d3"

export function indentedTree({
                                 svg,
                                 data, // hierarchy
                                 width = 1000,
                                 height = 1000,
                             }) {

    // Prepare all your data to build the indented tree
    let nodesUpdate, linksUpdate;

    const nodeHeight = 20

    svg.attr("height", nodeHeight * 2)

    //TODO: create the hierarchy out of the data.
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data);

    // TODO: go through each node and add any information that may help you building the interactive indented tree
    root.descendants().forEach((d, i) => {
        d.index = i;
        d.depth = d.depth;
        d._children = d.children;
        if (d.depth > 0) d.children = null;
    });

    console.log(root.links()); 

    // You can use this function to color your nodes, depending on its state
    const nodeColor = data => data.children ? "#73b6ff" : (data._children ? "#5886b0" : "#EEE")

    // Use this g element to draw your nodes
    const nodesGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes-group")

    // Use this g element to draw the links
    const linksGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links-group")

   // TODO: Draw the nodes as circles on the SVG
   // Use the index you calculated to get y, and its depth information to get x
    const nodes = nodesGroup.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(root.descendants(), d => d.data.name)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.depth;  // might need to be replaced or mutiplied with a constant
         })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.index;  // might need to be replaced or mutiplied with a constant
         })
        .attr("r", 5);  // radius of the circle

    // TODO: Draw the links
    // Remember, every link is a source - target (or parent to child) pair
    const links = linksGroup.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(root.links(), d => `${d.source.data.name}-${d.target.data.name}`)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
            .x(d => d.y)
            .y(d => d.x));
        

    function updateTree() {
        // TODO: Traverse the nodes in the current tree in a meaningful order, and add their index data (in which order are they shown vertically)

        // TODO: Add a title element in your nodes, so that on hover you can see a tooltip showing the node's path (e.g.: "Mammalia/Theria/Marsupialia/DASYUROMORPHIA")
        nodes.append("title")
        .text(d => d.data.name);

        // TODO: Make it interactive
        // Add a click event to each node, that causes the children of that node to be hidden/shown
        nodes.on("click", function(d) {
            // Hide or show the children of the clicked node here
              // If the node has children, hide them
              if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } 
            // If the node's children are hidden, show them
            else if (d._children) {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
        
            // After changing the node's children, update the tree
            updateTree();
          });

        // TODO: Add transitions
        // You can use d3.transition to achieve this
        // You can also use the complete .join(enter, update, exit) pattern. This may require for you to re-arrange your code a bit.
        nodes.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        })
        .attr("display", function(d) {
            // If the node has no children, hide it
            if (!d.children) {
                return "none";
            } 
            // If the node has children, show it
            else {
                return "";
            }
        });
      
      links.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
            + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
            + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
            + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
        })
        .attr("display", function(d) {
            // If the source node of the link has no children, hide the link
            if (!d.source.children) {
                return "none";
            } 
            // If the source node of the link has children, show the link
            else {
                return "";
            }
        });

        // Here we make the svg change its height together with the nodes shown
        const transitionSVG = d3.transition().duration(250)
        svg.transition(transitionSVG).attr("height", () => (root.descendants().length + 2) * nodeHeight)

    }

    function updateTree() {
        // Handle nodes
        const nodesUpdate = nodesGroup.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(root.descendants(), d => d.data.name)
            .attr("class", "node");
    
        nodesUpdate.enter()
            .append("g")
            .merge(nodesUpdate)
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
            });
    
        nodesUpdate.exit()
            .remove();
    
        // Handle links
        const linksUpdate = linksGroup.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(root.links(), d => `${d.source.data.name}-${d.target.data.name}`);
    
        linksUpdate.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .merge(linksUpdate)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
                    + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
                    + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
                    + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
            });
    
        linksUpdate.exit()
            .remove();
    }

}


And this is my document-embedding.js file:
import {
    tfidf,
    inverseDocumentFrequency,
    documentToWords,
  } from "./src/wordvector.js";

import * as d3 from "d3"

export function document_embedding({svg, movie_corpus}) {
    // log the corpus, so that you can analyse its stucture in the browser
    console.log(movie_corpus);

    // TODO: reduce each movie from the movie corpus to its description
    const descriptions = movie_corpus.map(movie => movie.description);
    console.log(descriptions);
    // TODO: use the function "documentToWords" to perform
    const wordsPerDescription = descriptions.map(description => documentToWords(description)); 
    // tokenization, stopword removal and lemmatizaion on 
    // the array of descriptions. You will get back an array of words for
    // each description.


    // calculate word vectors per genre
    // TODO: 1. calculate the genres from the movie corpus
    const genres = [...new Set(movie_corpus.map(movie => movie.genre))];
 

    // TODO: 2. get all words for each genre
    const wordsPerGenre = genres.map(genre => {
      return movie_corpus.filter(movie => movie.genre === genre).map(movie => documentToWords(movie.description));
    });


    // TODO: 3. create the dictionary (use the function "createDictionary" on
    // the array of words per genre)
    const dictionary = createDictionary(wordsPerGenre);
    
    /// TODO: 4. from the dictionary calculate the word vector for each genre
    // step 1: calculate the idf values for each term:
    //          you can use the function idfGenre() for it, it takes an array of arrays of words, the same as the dictionary function
    // step 2: calculate the tf values by counting each word of the dictionary in each genre 
    //          and weight it by the number of words in the genre
    // step 3: calculate the tf-idf scores per term and genre by multiplying both values
    // step 4: give back the word vector per genre
    const idfValues = inverseDocumentFrequency(wordsPerGenre);

    const wordVectors = genres.map((genre, i) => {
    const words = wordsPerGenre[i];
    const tfValues = dictionary.map(word => words.filter(w => w === word).length / words.length);
    const tfIdfValues = tfValues.map((tf, i) => tf * idfValues[i]);
    return tfIdfValues;
  });
 
  
    // TODO: calculate the distances between each pair of word vectors
    // and store them in a matrix, use either the euclidean distance,
    // the cosine similarity, or the manhattan distance
    const dists = wordVectors.map((vectorA, i) => {
      return wordVectors.map((vectorB, j) => {
          if (i === j) {
              return 0;
          } else {
              return euclidean_distance(vectorA, vectorB);
          }
      });
   });


    // then the multi-dimensional scaling is performed on your data
    // TODO: replace the "dists" with your distance matrix
    const dists2 = [[0.0, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0.0, 0.3], [0.2, 0.1, 0.0]];
    const positions = mds.classic(dists);
    console.log(positions);
  
    //TODO: encode the x,y coordinates
    // Channels: x -> x position, y -> y position
    // marks: points
    // please label the points with the genre name
    const points = svg.selectAll("circle").data(positions).enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d[0])
    .attr("cy", d => d[1])
    .attr("r", 5);

const labels = svg.selectAll("text").data(genres).enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", (d, i) => positions[i][0])
    .attr("y", (d, i) => positions[i][1])
    .text(d => d);
   

}

// given arrays of numbers A and B, calculate similarity
function cosine_similarity(A, B) {
    var dotproduct = 0;
    var mA = 0;
    var mB = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        dotproduct += A[i] * B[i];
        mA += A[i] * A[i];
        mB += B[i] * B[i];
    }

    mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
    mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
    var similarity = dotproduct / (mA * mB);

    return similarity;
  }

  // given arrays of numbers A and B, calculate distance
  function euclidean_distance(A, B) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        total += (A[i] - B[i])*(A[i] - B[i]);
    }
    return Math.sqrt(total);
  }

  // given arrays of numbers A and B, calculate distance
  function manhattan_distance(A, B) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        total += (A[i] - B[i]);
    }
    return total/A.length;
  }

  // given an array of arrays of words, calculate the dictionary
  // the dictionary is shortened by filtering the 20 most distictive 
  // words for each given group
  function createDictionary(wordsPerGroup) {
    const idfGenre = inverseDocumentFrequency(wordsPerGroup);

    const dictionary = Array.from(new Set(wordsPerGroup.map(document => {
        return tfidf(document, idfGenre)
        .sort((a,b) => d3.descending(a[1],b[1]))
        .map(entry => entry[0])
        .filter(word => word.length > 2)
        .slice(0, 20);
    }).flat()));
   return dictionary;
  }

I should have been able to see charts like the attached two pictures but right now it's just a blank. If anyone can point out where the errors are then I would really appreciate it. Indented tree Document Embedding

What errors appear within your browser's developer tools console?
